# bootstrap Table header fixed issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, tableheader

I'm using **bootstrap**.  I'm trying to use a fixed table header, but its not being fixed, it can be scrolled. I don't want to `scroll` a table header, I want to have a fixed  **table header**. 
Please help me to fix it.

This is my code sample:

**This is my code:**

```
  <div class="widget-content">
          <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <th class="text-center"> my</th>
              <th class="text-center"> text / line</th>
              <th  class="text-center">caps/ lock</th>
              <th  class="text-center">Value</th>
              <th  class="text-center">Qty</th>
              <th  class="text-center">other</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                <tr class="dt-picked">
                  <td class="text-center">
                      <span style="color:white; font-weight:bold;"> text</span>

                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center">
                    <p>text</p>

                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center ">
                    <p>text</p>
                   <p>text</p>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-center"> <p>text</p></td>
                  <td class="text-center b-color-1"><p>text</p></td>
                  <td>
                    class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" role="button">Sell</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>

              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-stripe">Total Cash</td>
                <td class="b-color-1"><p>text</p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-right no-stripe">Total Invested</td>
                <td class="b-color-1"><p>text</p></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="no-stripe"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-right bold no-stripe">Bottom Line</td>
                <td class="b-color-1 bold"><p>text</p></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="no-stripe"></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a fiddle for you

```
<thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>
        Table attribute name
        <div>Table attribute name</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        Value
        <div>Value</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        Description
        <div>Description</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/14995/

Answer (score 0):

Try using position Property on thead

```
 <thead style="position:absolute;">
              <th class="text-center"> my</th>
              <th class="text-center"> text / line</th>
              <th  class="text-center">caps/ lock</th>
              <th  class="text-center">Value</th>
              <th  class="text-center">Qty</th>
              <th  class="text-center">other</th>
              </thead>
```

Comment: sir, im used  `position:absolute`,after text is not align , `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`?

Comment: @core114  jut use an another property for  text "text-align:center"